# Selecting random values of an array of strings in C

Tags: c

I want to have an array of strings, and something return a random string from that array, so something like this:

```
 char* initialblow[] = {"hey", "hi", "hello"}; // this might be bigger or smaller
 char* secondblow[] = {"Bob", "Phil", "Sue"}; 
 int length1 = sizeof(initialblow)/sizeof(char); 
 int length2 = sizeof(secondblow)/sizeof(char);

 ...

 return initialblow[rand() % length1] + ", " + secondblow[rand() % length2]
```

Am I messing something really obvious up?  I haven't touched C for a long time and can't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
int length1 = sizeof(initialblow)/sizeof(char);
```

use

```
int length1 = sizeof(initialblow)/sizeof(*initialblow);
```

and instead of

```
return initialblow[rand() % length1] + ", " + secondblow[rand() % length2]
```

use something like

```
char out[256];
sprintf(out, "%s,%s", initialblow[rand() % length1], secondblow[rand() % length2]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick! I just looked up sprintf() and just so I'm clear, does this mean that if I were to print `out`, it'd be the string I wanted?

Comment: @Nick I'm returning back to this, what if I want to return `out`? Would I have a function that's something like:
`char* getOut() { return *out; }`, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Your computation of the length is wrong. `initialblow` is not an array of `char` but of `char*`:

```
int length1 = sizeof(initialblow)/sizeof(*initialblow);
```

Also, you can't concatenate string like this in C. You have to use `strcat` to concatenate a string into an existing one. For this either pass an extra `char []` parameter and fill it with the result or do some dynamic allocation to return a `char*`.

Comment: I always find it easier to remember `sizeof(initialblow)/sizeof(initialblow[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `initialblow[rand() % length1] + ", " + secondblow[rand() % length2]` concatenate like this. What you're doing here is `char + char* + char` - which is illegal.

`initialblow[rand() % length1]` is a `char`

`","` is a `char*`

`secondblow[rand() % length2]` is a `char`

If you really want to return a string, then make one (see Nick's answer). However, if you want to return it to the caller, instead of consuming it in the function then you've to go with dynamic memory allocation.